# Apache Spark: Classloader cannot find classDef in the jar

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, classloader

I'm running a job in Apache Spark in local mode that will save its result to s3a file system. Since Hadoop 2.6 doesn't have s3a:// implementation (or s3://, s3n://). I package an uber jar that includes all transitive dependency of hadoop-aws 2.6.0, and submit it with the jar of my main job.

However, when I test it with the following minimalistic code:

```
sc.parallelize(1 to 100).saveAsTextFile("s3a://***/test10/")
```

The compiler gave me this error in my first run:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain.<clinit>(AWSCredentialsProviderChain.java:41)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.initialize(S3AFileSystem.java:112)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2596)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2630)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2612)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:296)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkHadoopWriter$.createPathFromString(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:953)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:863)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.saveAsTextFile(RDD.scala:1290)
```

And if I try to run again, it gave me this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.initialize(S3AFileSystem.java:112)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2596)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2630)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2612)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:296)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkHadoopWriter$.createPathFromString(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:953)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:863)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.saveAsTextFile(RDD.scala:1290)
```

The strange thing is: Both LogFactory & AWSCredentialsProviderChain are in the uber jar I mentioned. I've also checked other jars, including the spark library on workers and jar of the my main job (already deployed to spark/worker directory), and could confirm that none of them has class with an identical name. So it cannot be a jar hell issue (Besides, in that case the thrown error should be a Property/MethodNotFoundError). Do you have any clue what may have happened and how to fix it?

Comment: Have you used a jar analyzer to verify the depa?  Can you post your build.sbt

Comment: I open all the jars manually to verify that they are there. For the build file, see https://github.com/tribbloid/spookystuff/blob/improved-lookup/lib/pom.xml

Comment: @tribbloid have you fixed this issue? I'm struggling with Spark 1.5.0 w/ Hadoop 2.6.0 trying to modify classpath, shadowjars etc and it won't help.

Answer (score 2):

I met a similar problem before and my solution was to add the uber jar itself to --driver-class-path while you run spark-submit. Your uber-jar isn't directly executed by JVM. Instead it is run by Spark's some sort of driver wrapper. Add the uber jar to the driver's classpath seems unnecessary but can sometimes solve some strange NoClassDefFoundError. I'm not sure if it can solve your problem but it's worth a try.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try this immediately

Comment: No, but it is marginally better: the s3 and s3n works for local-cluster mode (or simulation mode), but it throws the same ClassNotFound error in real cluster mode.

Comment: Try to set spark.executor.userClassPathFirst=true when you submit the app by specifying "--conf spark.executor.userClassPathFirst=true" to your spark-submit command

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion, after spark 1.4.0 is released and the bug on S3 access is still marked as 'not resolved', I kind of already give up and revert back to hadoop 2.4. Tackling version conflicts in dependency management is neither efficient nor safe. Changing the override sequence may trigger some other problems, or even worse, trigger a hidden problem that will only become imminent after deployed into production

Comment: Let's get back to a solution after the fix to [SPARK-7442] is released

Comment: Was this ever resolved? I am having similar issues with Spark 1.6.1